# How to use Polylines and Polygons with the official flutter_map plugin?

Tags: flutter

I'm using this plugin (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_map) because it's from the flutter team, bug how can I use Polyline/Polygons?

thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Support for this is work in progress.
The issue to follow is https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17832

There are pull requests with basic support that could be tested already using a Git dependency

- https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1049
- https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1121

Comment: Thank you. I used the Polyline and it worked like a charm. But my project needs Polygon. Can I use it or it is not done yet?

Comment: Sorry, don't know. I haven't tried. I just remembered seeing the discussiins in the links I posted.